# When converting to Judaism, can three rabbis dissuading a convert one time each count?

Tags: conversion-to-judaism

When converting to Judaism, can three rabbis dissuading a convert one time each count? Or  does it have to be one rabbi, dissuading a convert three times? What if it's one rabbi that dissuaded a convert twice and one other rabbi dissuading them once? Does that count? What are the laws in Halakhah that speak about dissuading a convert?

If it's one rabbi, 3 dissuasion to a convert, why would there need to be 3 rabbis in the bais din to determine their conversion status?

What counts as dissuasion? What's the difference between rejection and dissuasion?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya. I'm having trouble understanding your question. I don't know if it's a grammatical problem or some piece is missing. Can you please explain what type of "rejection" you refer to. Do you mean rabbis that reject to the conversion process, itself, or are they rejecting the convert for some reason? What do you mean by "count" - for what purpose?

Comment: Hi, thank you. The rejection I was referring to and re-worded above is "dissuading" a convert from converting. Both? Dissuading the conversion process itself...and dissuading a convert for specific reasons?  What defines rejecting a convert? What are the differences between rejection and dissuasion? Please help me as to what counts during the process of Halakhah.

Comment: Hi Prism. Remember to [edit] your clarifications into the post itself so everyone can see them

Comment: So what you're asking is whether all three of the rabbis on the Beis Din have to dissuade a potential convert, or if one rabbi is enough (and the other two can encourage him/her)?

Comment: ezra, yes that too. I am initially asking if 3 rabbis dissuading a convert once each time counts, or does it specifically have to be 1 rabbi dissuading a convert 3 times.

Comment: I'm actually not aware of a Halakhic requirement to dissuade or reject a potential convert any number of times by any number of people, so I'd be surprised to see rigorous discussion of this question

Answer (score 4):

There is no halachic basis for rejecting a convert three times. The Shulchon Oruch merely brings down to inform a potential ger of the challenges of being a Yid, the concept of s'char v'onesh (reward and punishment) in relation to the mitzvos, and a basic education as to keeping the mitzvos.

(Shulchon Oruch, Yoreh Deah 268, discusses the halochos of geiris.)

Answer (score 0):

Ruth Rabbah 2:16 actually quotes the idea and source of rejecting three times (three mentions of rejecting in the story of Ruth), but seemingly it is not brought down l'halacha.

Very similar question, with quotation and translation of the source above:

[Source for discouraging converts](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/90436/source-for-discouraging-converts)